BusyBox Linux sed does not replace first line when I run this command
I have a script that needs to replace the first line that contains a specific phrase. It should not replace any other lines of text.
Using this:
sed -i '1,/old/ s/.*old.*/new/' temp 

This correctly replaces the entire line containing 'old' with 'new'.  But I noticed that if 'old' is on the first line, this does not work.  I tried using 0 instead of 1 and it does not work at all, no replacements.
Please let me know if anyone has another way to do this that will also work on the first line.
The contents of the temp file are:
line 1 has 'old value' here.
line 2 has 'old value' here.

This is on an embedded device that uses sed as part of BusyBox.
Versions are:
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2022-11-02 08:55:42 PDT) multi-call binary.
$ sed --version
This is not GNU sed version 4.0
$

The sed C source from BusyBox is posted at: https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/editors/sed.c

By "this does not work", I assume you mean more lines are replaced than desired.

You are using the substitute command inside a range test.
The form is: address1 , address2 command
Addresses are generally specified as an absolute number, $ (final line of file), or a regular expression.
The significant point is that the test for address2 does not happen until the line after the line that matches address1.
In your command:

1 = address1
/old/ = address2

This means /old/ is not checked until line 2.
GNU sed has a non-standard extension where address1 can be 0, which is taken to mean that the range begins at the start of the file (a notional line zero) and testing for address2 begins from the first line. It seems busybox sed does not support that extension.
You could rewrite your script as, for example:
sed -i '
    /.*old.*/!b
    s//new/
:loop
    n
    bloop
' temp


if desired line is not found, branch to end of script (i.e. just print)
otherwise:

make the substitution
loop reading the remaining lines (with implicit print before each read)



Specifying an empty regex to s/// reuses the last RE used in the last command applied.

Could you explain how your rewrite works?

@Barmar better?

Yes. The beginning of the answer is just a long-winded way of saying that in a range specification, the range end doesn't include the start.

Thanks very much! Your script works perfectly!  What I meant by 'does not work' is that when I used 0, nothing was replaced.  Anyway, I will implement your answer.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -zi 's/.*old.*/new/m' file

Use the -z option to slurp the file into memory and the m multiline substitution flag to replace the first line that contains old by new.

Just use awk for clarity, simplicity, extensibility, robustness, portability, etc., e.g. given this input:
$ printf 's172t\nuoldv\nwoldx\ny192z\n' > file
$ cat file
s172t
uoldv
woldx
y192z

which would have the expected output:
s172t
new
woldx
y192z

then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box you could do the following without reading the whole file into memory and without duplicating any conditions (common for range expression solutions):
$ awk '!f && index($0,"old"){ $0="new"; f=1 } 1' file
s172t
new
woldx
y192z

f is just a flag variable I'm using to remember when we have found the string we were looking for and done the replacement. 1 is an awk idiom representing a true condition which causes awk to print the current input, shorthand for writing {print} so I could have written the above more clearly as awk '!found && index($0,"old"){ $0="new"; found=1 } { print }' file but chose brevity since those abbreviations are very common, simple, and idiomatic.
That has the benefit that it'll work as-is even if the old and new strings contain regexp metachars or backreference metachars. For example if you want to change the first line containing the string 1.2 instead of old into the string a&b instead of new then given this input:
$ printf 's172t\nu1.2v\nw1.2x\ny192z\n' > file
$ cat file
s172t
u1.2v
w1.2x
y192z

which has expected output:
s172t
a&b
w1.2x
y192z

let's try it with a sed script but we don't get the desired output:
$ sed '
/.*1.2.*/!b
s//a&b/
:loop
    n
    bloop
' file
as172tb
u1.2v
w1.2x
y192z

and another sed script also doesn't produce the desired output:
$ sed -z 's/.*1.2.*/a&b/m' file
as172tb
u1.2v
w1.2x
y192z

and now the above awk script does produce the desired output:
$ awk '!f && index($0,"1.2"){ $0="a&b"; f=1 } 1' file
s172t
a&b
w1.2x
y192z

That's because sed doesn't have any way to work with literal strings while awk does but awk can also work with regexps if/when desired, e.g. to do what the above sed commands are doing:
$ awk '!f && sub(/.*1.2.*/,"a&b"){ f=1 } 1' file
as172tb
u1.2v
w1.2x
y192z

See Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed for what you'd need to do in sed to duplicate the functionality of the first awk script above.
Since you're using sed -i you can use awk -i inplace similarly if your awk supports it (e.g. GNU awk does) or with any tool you can always add > tmp && mv tmp file to the end of the command line to update the input (tools with -i use a temp file internally anyway).
If you really wanted to use a range expression for some reason, awk also supports them but unlike sed it doesn't skip the line that matches the start of the range expression when testing for the end of the range expression, e.g. given this input:
$ printf 'a_foo\nb_foo\n'
a_foo
b_foo

below are 2 equivalent-looking scripts intended to match from the start of the input to the first line containing foo and so should only output the first line, a_foo.
Fail:
$ printf 'a_foo\nb_foo\n' | sed -n '1,/foo/p'
a_foo
b_foo

Success:
$ printf 'a_foo\nb_foo\n' | awk 'NR==1,/foo/'
a_foo

Range expressions are rarely, if ever, the best solution to any problem though, see Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?.
